# We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now

Tags: magento2

When i am trying to add product to cart, it is showing "We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now".
[image]

This is my exception.log file output:

```
#44 /mnt/thebodyshoplive/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/VarnishPlugin.php(55): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#45 /mnt/thebodyshoplive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\VarnishPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#46 /mnt/thebodyshoplive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'dispatch', Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Array, 'front-controlle...')
#47 /mnt/thebodyshoplive/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(73): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#48 /mnt/thebodyshoplive/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#49 /mnt/thebodyshoplive/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#50 /mnt/thebodyshoplive/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#51 /mnt/thebodyshoplive/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#52 /mnt/thebodyshoplive/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#53 {main} [] []strong text
```